# Creating address callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coinbase-api

I'm trying to use Coinbase's Ruby API to manage users' wallet in my app. Currently, upon sign up, a new wallet is created for the user.

```
def create_account
  wallet = Coinbase::Wallet::Client.new(api_key: ENV["COINBASE_KEY"], api_secret: ENV["COINBASE_SECRET"])
  mAccount = check_account
  if mAccount.nil?
    mAccount = wallet.create_account(name: self.email)
  end
  newaddr = mAccount.create_address
  newaddr = newaddr["address"]
  account = Account.new
  account.address = newaddr
  account.user_id = self.id
  account.balance = mAccount["balance"]["amount"]
  account.account_id = mAccount["id"]
  account.save
end
```

This is the code I use to create a new wallet and an address inside the wallet. My question is: How do I attach the callback url to the address from an api call? I'd want to include several parameters like "secret" and "account_id".

Comment: Are you creating a unique wallet/account for each of your users,  belonging to a single Coinbase user? I don't think it's documented, but I believe there's a limit to the number of wallets an account can have.

Comment: Yes, my intention is to create a unique wallet per user.